# Enable UNIQUE CONSTRAINT = Violation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

When enabling a unique constraint I get a violation. 
How can I select those rows which cause a violation?

The unique constraint is build from 6 columns in total.

Comment: basically it has entries which are non unique which can be traced by queries having filters with `group by` `count < 1`

Comment: `select column1,column2,...column6,COUNT(*) from table group by column1,...column6 having COUNT(*) > 1`

Answer (score 2):

create an appropriate exceptions report table to accept information from the EXCEPTIONS option of the ENABLE clause before enabling the constraint. You can create an exception table by executing the UTLEXCPT.SQL script or the UTLEXPT1.SQL script.

```
ALTER TABLE dept ENABLE PRIMARY KEY EXCEPTIONS INTO EXCEPTIONS;


SELECT deptno, dname, loc FROM dept, EXCEPTIONS
    WHERE EXCEPTIONS.constraint = 'SYS_C00610'
    AND dept.rowid = EXCEPTIONS.row_id;
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general005.htm#ADMIN11553 for detailed information

Comment: ... and also give your constraints explicit names of course. System generated names can lead to import/export problems, and make constraint violation messages rather obscure.